# How to handle the integer textbox with value 0

Tags: c#

I have 3 textbox

1,Age(year),
2,Age(month),
3,Age(Day))

By Default all 3 texbox value is 0(integer) which means the object assigned to each control is holding the value 0.

```
  ibusbus.icdobus.user_month =0

  ibusbus.icdobus.user_year=0

  ibusbus.icdobus.user_Day=0
```

Now I need to validation if the user is  make a empty of those textboxes.

So what I did is

```
   public bool IsUserAgeYearisNull()
    {
        return (ibusbus.icdobus.user_year <= 0);
    }
 public bool IsUserAgeMonthisNull()
    {
        return (ibusbus.icdobus.user_month <= 0);
    }

  public bool IsUserAgeDayisNull()
    {
        return (ibusbus.icdobus.user_day <= 0);
    }
```

So If user is make empty it is throwing a message.Here there is no issues

But in case User is  enter year as 12 and enter 0 for both month and age.It is showing erro for month and Day that user need to enter the value.Here the user can enter 0 but it should not throw error.

Comment: TextBox contains strings not integers, what kind of datatype are user_age_year and friends?

Comment: Why you don't obtain age from year and month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check all condition in all functions.

```
public bool IsUserAgeYearisNull()
{
    if (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_month == 0 && ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_day == 0)
        return (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_year <= 0);
    else
        return true;
}
public bool IsUserAgeMonthisNull()
{
    if (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_year == 0 && ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_day == 0)
        return (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_month <= 0);
    else
        return true
}

public bool IsUserAgeDayisNull()
{
    if (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_year == 0 && ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_month == 0)
        return (ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_day <= 0);
    else
        return true;
}
```

you can also create a common function.

```
public bool isValid()
{
    return (busCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_year > 0 || 
           ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_month > 0 ||
           ibusCalcWiz.icdoCalcWiz.user_age_day > 0);
}
```

and call from all function. Like :

```
public bool IsUserAgeDayisNull()
{
    return isValid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RangeValidator` for each of `TextBox`es.

Answer (score 0):

Using RangeValidator as suggested earlier would be a better idea rather than writing lots of code. it will become hard to maintain the code in long run.